# "Debug Assertion Failed!" Error from using the Sort function from the List Container

Tags: c++, list

I am receiving the following error compiling in Visual Studio 2010.

Debug Assertion Failed!
Expression: invalid operator<

It is a result of the following comparison function:

```
bool ShortestJob(Process_T *first, Process_T *second)
{
    int firstRemaining = first->cpuTime - first->cpuProgress;
    int secondRemaining = second->cpuTime - second->cpuProgress;
    if ((firstRemaining < secondRemaining) || ((first->cpuProgress == second->cpuProgress) && (first->processID < second->processID))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The field processID is an int. How may I resolve this bug?

Comment: What's the type of `processID` field?

Comment: Yes, it is pure c++; processID is an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 will assert in debug build if your compare function object for sorting is incorrect and doesn't follow strict weak ordering.

Try changing your function to

```
bool ShortestJob(Process_T *first, Process_T *second)
{
    int firstRemaining = first->cpuTime - first->cpuProgress;
    int secondRemaining = second->cpuTime - second->cpuProgress;
    if ((firstRemaining < secondRemaining) || ((firstRemaining == secondRemaining) && (first->processID < second->processID))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

They way you have defined the operator is incorrect. You should only compare processID for if and only if the first criteria which in your case is **(firstRemaining ,secondRemaining)** are equal